# How would I determine how large an M/M/c queue grows after a certain amount of time?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, queueing-theory, operations-research, birth-death-process

Most of the reading on queueing theory I've done focuses on when the arrival rate is less than the service rate so that the queue doesn't explode. However, if I have a queueing system (either M/M/1 or M/M/c) where the arrival rate is greater than the service rate, how can I find properties such as the following:

- How large will the queueing system grow after a certain amount of time?
- What is the probability that the expected wait time upon arrival will be greater than a certain amount of time at time t?
- How many servers should the system have so that the queue never grows beyond a certain size in a fixed amount of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm many years removed from messing with queuing systems, so take this with a grain of salt. I think you can (theoretically) answer the first two questions, and the third with some trial and error (iterating over server counts), using the [backward Kolmogorov equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_backward_equations_(diffusion)). That requires solving a system of simultaneous PDEs. Alternatively, if you are asking about a specific system rather than asking a general theoretical question, you could probably get reasonably accurate results (while consuming fewer brain cells) doing it via discrete event simulation.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a Continuous Time Markov Chain to do the first two; the last one is infinite, since however many servers you have, there will always be some positive probability that there will be N customers coming (for any N). (In an M/M/c queue, the probability that 1000000 customers show up in 0.5 seconds is positive so long as the arrival rate is)

Comment: continuous time markov chain

Comment: I realize that an M/M/c queueing system can be modeled as a continuous time markov chain - more specifically, a birth-death process - however, in everything that I've read so far, I haven't found anything about determining the size of the system after a certain amount of time.

Comment: The steady-state behavior of M/M/c queues has been extensively studied. Balance eqns can be solved to give the steady-state distn based on the arrival rate $\lambda$ and the service rate $\mu\, (\lambda < c\mu)$ of each of the $c$ servers. Then one can find the avg nr $L$ of people in the system, the avglength $W = L/\lambda$ of time a customer spends in the system, the avg nr of people waiting for service and the avg length of time a customer spends waiting for service. The eqn $L = \lambda W$ is called Little's Law. See books and sites on queues, Operations Rsch, and Stochastic Processes.

Comment: I'm not interested in the steady-state behavior of the queueing system in question, as the arrival rate is time dependent. I want to know how it behaves during peak hours, to see how long it can handle increased traffic. Therefore, Little's Law is not helpful in this situation.

Comment: Hmm, the fact that it is time dependent really messes things up; your best bet is to solve a bunch of ODEs.